# Alternative for export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Tags: environment-variables

I've been using Ansible to provision an ec2 instance. Every time I start the VM I have to execute

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ACCESS-KEY-ID 
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = SECRET-ACCESS-KEY
```

before running the ansible-playbook to provision/configure the instance.

I have written a playbook which executes above commands using raw module of Ansible, even after executing that playbook I have to manually execute those commands before I can run the `provision.yml` script.

Is there an efficient way of doing these from the playbook itself????, because I am actually working on some automation job which doesn't encourage manual execution of commands.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible can set environment variables:

In your playbook:

```
- name: "Simple playbook"
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
     - aws
  environment:
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
```

I would strongly recommend learning how to use [ansible-vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) as a quick an easy way to store credentials in Ansible.

Also note, that if you are using the [ec2.py](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) Dynamic inventory script, the above solution will not work. The inventory is loaded before the environment is set by the playbook. In this case, the best option would be to use one of the alternate [AWS credential methods](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html). One simple method is a `~/.boto` file with the contents:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET
```